# Import two columns from Excel into existing Access2010 table gives error using transferspreadsheet

Tags: ms-access-2010, import-from-excel

I have an excel spreadsheet, with 12 columns, where I only need to import data based on the last two (The rest are needed to fill out the last column.)

[Excel table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TliIq.png)

[Acces table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c8ts9.png)

As shown on the picture I have a table in Access called "ProjektDelledning" where the two columns DelledningID and SaneringsmetKode are already present. If a DelledningID is already present it needs to update the SaneringsmetKode, if it isn't present in the table, it needs to add the value. So Delledning 258 should have a SaneringsmetKode = 1 in Acces after import and so forth.

So far I've tried using this:

```
Public Function Import2Columns()
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12Xml, "ProjektDelledning", "C:\Users\JGJ\Desktop\Sanering.xlsx", True, "Concatenate!L:M" 
End Function
```

I get an error saying that Access was unable to append all the data to the table. The Contents of field in 0 reocrd(s) were deleted, and 0 record(s) were lost due to key violations...

It is worth noting that in the Access table, both ProjektID and DelledningID is a key.

Any help as to how I can get a correct import using transferspreadsheet or a different method works. I would like to make the import work using a Macro.

Comment: Your pictures are blocked from viewing.

Comment: Apologies. Should be fixed now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A method could be to import to a temp table (or just *link* the range).

Then, using this, run a combined update/append query.

This old tip from *Smart Access* is one of my favourites:

> Update and Append Records with One Query
>
> By Alan Biggs
>
> Did you know that you can use an update query in Access to both
>   update  and add records at the same time? This is useful if you have
>   two  versions of a table, tblOld and tblNew, and you want to integrate
>   the  changes from tblNew into tblOld.
>
> Follow these steps:
>
> 1. Create an update query and add the two tables. Join the two tables  by dragging the key field of tblNew onto the matching field of tblOld.
> 2. Double-click on the relationship and choose the join option that  includes all records from tblNew and only those that match from 
>      tblOld.
> 3. Select all the fields from tblOld and drag them onto the QBE grid.
> 4. For each field, in the Update To cell type in tblNew.FieldName,  where FieldName matches the field name of tblOld.
> 5. Select Query Properties from the View menu and change Unique  Records to False. (This switches off the DISTINCTROW option in the SQL
>      view. If you leave this on you'll get only one blank record in your 
>      results, but you want one blank record for each new record to be added
>      to tblOld.)
> 6. Run the query and you'll see the changes to tblNew are now in  tblOld.
>
>    This will only add records to tblOld that have been added to tblNew. 
>      Records in tblOld that aren't present in tblNew will still remain in 
>      tblOld.

Comment: Tried what you describe, but not sure if I did it correctly. When I run the update query, it asks to update 28 rows (which is correct), however when I press Ok it gives an error message saying that 5 records due to validation rule violations could not be updated.    [UpdateQuery](http://i.imgur.com/0vJJrYu.png)           It correctly updates 22 records with the right number.

Comment: I believe you will also need a relation between the two SaneringsmetKode. A compound key.

Comment: Managed to get it to work, there was a mismatch between data keys, it would not accept a Null value, so for those I made an Iif that changes Null to 0. And now it works. Just one more question, can I run this update and append query from a macro?

Comment: Yes. Save the query with a meaningful name. Then create a new macro and select a macro command like "Run action query" and specify the name of the query - can't recall the exact wording as I don't use macros.