# Access SQL Append/Update Distinct

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2016

I'm trying to update a query I have, Access SQL (for now). It is currently a make table, but I want to change it into an update query, but only if the information isn't already in the end table.

Here is the current "Make Table" Query:

SELECT DISTINCT dbo_Us_postal_codes.[City]
   ,dbo_Us_postal_codes.[State] INTO dbo_ActiveZipCodes
   FROM dbo_General_Client_List INNER JOIN dbo_Us_postal_codes ON 
   dbo_General_Client_List.ZipCode = dbo_Us_postal_codes.[Zip Code]
   WHERE (((dbo_General_Client_List.ActiveCompany)=Yes));

US Postal Codes is a list of all US zipcodes, and their corresponding City, State.

What I want to do, is as General_Client_List is updated, run this query and add to ActiveZipCodes if the city/state combo isn't already there.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Import two columns from Excel into existing Access2010 table gives error using transferspreadsheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36857499/import-two-columns-from-excel-into-existing-access2010-table-gives-error-using-t)

Comment: Don't mind the title of the link above.

Answer (score 0):

Add dbo_ActiveZipCodes to your query window. Join the City and state fields from the source table with an Left join to the matching fields in the dbo_ActiveZipCodes. Make the criteria for both Is Null.

Obviously test it as as select query first.